# Probability of a series of events which may be recursive

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have a fair coin and a fair die. If I flip the coin and get heads, I note that I get heads and stop. If I get tails, I then roll the dice. If the dice roll results in a 4 or higher, I note the result and stop. If dice roll results in a 3 or less, I start over with the coin and repeat until eventually reaching a terminal state (either a head on the coin or a 4 or higher from the dice)

What I'd like to know is how to analytically determine the probability of each the terminal states for any given attempt, assuming that you always go until you reach a terminal state.

The recursion is really throwing me for a loop, I'm not even sure what the proper term for a situation such as this is.

Comment: Hint: Can you analyze the following problem: "I have a fair coin. If I flip the coin and get heads, I note that I get heads and stop. If I get tails, I start over and repeat until eventually reaching the terminal state of a heads." If you can, can you analyze how that new problem relates to the original one?

Comment: The recursion translates pretty directly into a linear equation for, say, the probability $p$ that you stop because of the coin flip in which $p$ appears on both sides. Solve that equation.